# How to detect that the application is being visited through a homescreen bookmark (embedded)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am writing a react native application with expo SDK36.

When a user visit the website, the manifest is used with splash and favicon to produce a nice PWA.

If I add a bookmark on my home screen with safari or chrome, I get my application available without any store installation and without the search bar from the browser.

How can I detect that the app is running   in an embedded webview ?

Comment: I already got an an answer, but I'd like to see if someone has already something tested bulletproof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect whether your web app is running in browser or as standalone using *display mode*.

If you want to detect the display mode for styling purpose then read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode).

Alternatively, you can detect display mode via javascript as below.

```
  if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
                 console.log("This is running as standalone.");
     }
```

Another simple way is you can append a query string to your start url to detect if, PWA is running.

```
  "start_url": "./?mode=standalone"
```

Comment: Where do you configure `start_url`

Comment: I've just tested `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches` and it work great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry but I had to unaccept the answer, apparently, this does not detect on iOS iPhone 6 Safari progressive web application installed from safari directly.  `alert(window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);` return false, do you know how i can detect being a PWA in iOS?