# How to find out the site opened on mobile as a native application (PWA) or on a browser

Tags: javascript, html, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have a site created with PWA technology, and I need to know when the role of how to find out the site was opened on mobile as a native application (PWA) or on a browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742390/javascript-to-check-if-pwa-or-mobile-web

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to check if PWA or Mobile Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742390/javascript-to-check-if-pwa-or-mobile-web)

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625850/1828907).

Comment: sorry but your examples do not help me i get the same data